# How to use threads to process all data of python list simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, list

I have a list of strings, which is used for processing some data.
Data processing for all strings does not affect result of other string..

```
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
   def run(self):
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
      print ("Exiting " + self.name)

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
   while counter:
      if exitFlag:
         threadName.exit()
      time.sleep(delay)
      print ("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
      counter -= 1

myList = ['string0', 'string1', 'string2']

def processFunc():
    count = 0
    for data in myList:
        count += 1
        mythread = myThread(count, "Thread-" + str(count), count)
        mythread.start()
        mythread.join()

processFunc()
```

This is executing in proper sequence, and not simultaneously.
How can I implement it using threads, so that all data is processed simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join()` waits for the thread to finish , so you have to call later after starting all thread.

```
def processFunc():
    count = 0
    mythreads=[]
    for data in myList:
        count += 1
        mythread = myThread(count, "Thread-" + str(count), count)
        mythread.start()
        mythreads.append(mythread)
    for mythread in mythreads:
        mythread.join()

processFunc()
```

Comment: If i don't use .join(), then will there be any complication in the execution?

Comment: Nope, unless you need all processed data for further process